# after upgrade to 13.10 gnome top panel empty and nothing can be added

Tags: upgrade, gnome-panel

I have just updated ubuntu from raring ringtale to saucy salamander. I'm using the classic desktop since many versions and it always survived the upgrade.

But now my top panel is empty. It is there and expands, but there is nothing in it. Aplications, Places.. my launchers and the login/out, wireless.. area are all gone. 
For some reason it has a white line on the bottom, but otherwise it is completly empty.

At the end of the upgrade I was asked if I want to keep some obsolete packages, I clicked remove. --> do I need to add some packages again? Which? (can I somehow check what was removed?)

Some random information that might give clues:

My Bottom Panel is just like before.

gnome-session-flashback is installed.

if I Alt + rightclick it and select add to Panel and add things, nothing changes, the Panel remains deserted.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why/how this solved the issue but ALT + rightclick > remove Panel on the top-panel and ALT + rightclick > new Panel on the bottom Panel, gave me a new top-Panel where I could add things no problem.